# Linear and Relative Layout parameters exceed device screen in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm not sure if this is a glitch or not, but the realtime XML editor in Android Studio is showing that my layouts are going all the way under the navigation bar at the bottom of the screen. I tried changing the height to wrap_content but it still was unusually low.

[image: You can see how the blue selection lines run low on the device.]

You can see how the blue selection lines run low on the device.

Comment: Please paste your code.

Comment: try to clean and re-build project. usually that one worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I realized the activity had scrolling view enabled. I didn't initially notice this. I apologize.